# lightbox effect with video playing using jquery?

Tags: jquery, audio, video, lightbox

I'm looking for a jQuery lightbox plugin that will be used to play a video. In the browser, clicking a thumbnail image of the video will open the lightbox modal and play the video as well as play audio also can any one guide me

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Fancybox(http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) They support playing youtube video in a lightbox. If you are looking to play videos not on youtube, you could also use fancybox to load an iframe with the video or audio that you want to play.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to Colorbox. Lightweight, attractive, great support for pretty much any content you throw at it. Still the most popular jQuery lightbox as far as I know, too.

http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/